# How to cluster based on ssdeep?

Tags: perl, hadoop, cluster-analysis

Hi I am trying to find the groups out of files based on ssdeep.

I have generated ssdeep of files and kept it in csv file.

I am parsing the file in perl script as follows:

```
foreach( @all_lines )
{
    chomp;
    my $line = $_;

    my @split_array = split(/,/, $line);
    my $md5 = $split_array[1];
    my $ssdeep = $split_array[4];

    my $blk_size = (split(/:/, $ssdeep))[0];

    if( $blk_size ne "")
    {
        my $cluster_id = check_In_Cluster($ssdeep);

        print WFp "$cluster_id,$md5,$ssdeep\n"; 
    }
}
```

This also checks whether the ssdeep is present in previously clustered group and if not creates new group.

Code for chec_In_Cluster

```
my $ssdeep = shift;
my $cmp_result;

if( $cluster_cnt > 0 ) {
    $cmp_result = ssdeep_compare( $MRU_ssdeep, $ssdeep );
    if( $cmp_result > 85 ) {
        return $MRU_cnt;
    }
}

my $d = int($cluster_cnt/4);
my $thr1 = threads->create(\&check, 0, $d, $ssdeep);
my $thr2 = threads->create(\&check, $d, 2*$d, $ssdeep);
my $thr3 = threads->create(\&check, 2*$d, 3*$d, $ssdeep);
my $thr4 = threads->create(\&check, 3*$d, $cluster_cnt, $ssdeep);

my ($ret1, $ret2, $ret3, $ret4);
$ret1 = $thr1->join();
$ret2 = $thr2->join();
$ret3 = $thr3->join();
$ret4 = $thr4->join();
if($ret1 != -1) {
    $MRU_ssdeep = $ssdeep;
    $MRU_cnt = $ret1;
    return $MRU_cnt;    
} elsif($ret2 != -1) {
    $MRU_ssdeep = $ssdeep;
    $MRU_cnt = $ret2;
    return $MRU_cnt;    
} elsif($ret3 != -1) {
    $MRU_ssdeep = $ssdeep;
    $MRU_cnt = $ret3;
    return $MRU_cnt;    
} elsif($ret4 != -1) {
    $MRU_ssdeep = $ssdeep;
    $MRU_cnt = $ret4;
    return $MRU_cnt;    
} else {
    $cluster_base[$cluster_cnt] = $ssdeep;
    $MRU_ssdeep = $ssdeep;
    $MRU_cnt = $cluster_cnt;
    $cluster_cnt++;
    return $MRU_cnt;    
}
```

and the code for chech:

```
sub check($$$) {
    my $from = shift;
    my $to = shift;
    my $ssdeep = shift;

    for( my $icnt = $from; $icnt < $to; $icnt++ ) {
        my $cmp_result = ssdeep_compare( $cluster_base[$icnt], $ssdeep );
        if( $cmp_result > 85 ) {
            return $icnt;
        }
    }
return -1;
}
```

But this process takes very much time( for 20-30MB csv file it takes 8-9Hours).
I have also tried using multithreading while checking in Cluster but not much help i got from this.

Since their is no need of csv parser like Text::CSV (because of less operation on csv) i didn't used it.

can anybody please solve my issue? Is it possible to use hadoop or some other frameworks for  grouping based on ssdeep?

Answer (score 1):

There is a hint from [Optimizing ssDeep for use at scale (2015-11-27)](https://www.virusbulletin.com/virusbulletin/2015/11/optimizing-ssdeep-use-scale).

1. Depends on your purpose, loop and match SSDEEP in different chunk size will create a N x (N-1) hash comparison.  Unless you need to find partial contents, otherwise, avoid it.
2. It is possible to breakdown of the hash index in step 1 as suggested in the article. This is a better way for partial contents match with different chunk size.
3. It is possible to reduce SSDEEP hash by grouping similar hash by generate a "distance cousin" hash.